# When reading a text file, why do I get b' in front of each line?

Tags: python, file-io

Not sure what's going on here. I have a text file with the following contents:

```
1999,3,Rep Armey, Richard K.,[TX-26],0
1999,4,Rep Armey, Richard K.,[TX-26],0
1999,5,Rep Armey, Richard K.,[TX-26],0
1999,6,Rep Hyde, Henry J.,[IL-6],0
1999,7,Rep Talent, Jim,[MO-2],11,Rep DeMint, Jim,[SC-4],...
...
```

then I read it in using this code in python 3.3:

```
with open(bill_file_name,'rb') as input_file:
    lines=input_file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line_list=str(line).split(',')
    session=line_list[0]
```

when I do `print(session)` I get `b'1999` for all of the entries.

What's going on? How do I avoid this?

Comment: You probably want to use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), which has fairly specific requirements for how you open the file (in Python 3, you want `open(filename, 'r', newline="")`).

Comment: I haven't had luck with the csv module or pandas because of lines like the last one, which extends with ~33 more columns.

Comment: I think the regular `csv.reader` can handle rows with arbitrary numbers of columns, though I've not actually tried it in that context. Parsing the list it gives you for each row might be a chore, but probably no more so than you're already facing using `line.split(',')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because you opened the file in binary mode.
Try `open(bill_file_name,'r')`

Answer (score 2):

That's because you have the `b` (binary) option enabled while reading. Use the following.

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

for line in lines:
    line_list=str(line).split(',')
    session=line_list[0]


>>> print(session)
1999
```